Struggling with the book Challenge and thrills of pre college mathematics
I am a highschool student and I am preparing for IOQM (which is the first level for IMO qualification in india, the exam is objective type), I got the book"Challenge and Thrills of Pre-College Mathematics" but I am struggling to solve questions from the book it has already been 2 months and I am still on the third chapter although I was also doing "Elementary number theory by David M Burton" in between,  Since the exam is expected to be in August or September next year shall I leave this book and try a different one or skip the geometry part because it is very hard. Also is the book good for ioqm as the exam is mostly objective but the book has a lot of 'prove that' question which are subjective.
Objective questions require us to fill the numericals answer like MCQ but subjective questions are questions whose answer format can be different for everyone such as proof based questions.

If proofs are subjective, then so is everything else in mathematics.

What do you mean by "subjective" here?  Can you give an example or two?

In any case, I'd be hesitant to recommend anything as I am not familiar with that qualifying exam.  I suggest speaking to your instructors, or other people who know the exam and who know you.

@PaulTanenbaum I think they mean "subjective" in the sense that it does not have a fixed answer (proofs can be different, writing style can be different from person to person) whereas "objective" questions like MCQ or True/False have exactly one answer.
